# kernel module's reference count

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a module to maintain, and it appears it has issues with reference counter being kept in the kernel, which results in that I'm unable to rmmod my module, after I kill the daemon opening 3 raw sockets to the module. Interestingly, after loading the daemon 'lsmod' displays 6 references to the module exist, I'd expect only three.

This is occuring on ARM-based embedded system with Linux-2.6.31, and rmmod doesn't have 'force' mode to try enforce unload a module (it's anyway not good idea).

I've analyzed the code and here is what I have:
1) The module creates new socket address family AF_HSL and registers with the kernel:

```
static struct proto_ops SOCKOPS_WRAPPED (hsl_ops) = {
  family:       AF_HSL,

  owner:        THIS_MODULE,
  release:      hsl_sock_release,
  bind:         _hsl_sock_bind,
  connect:      sock_no_connect,
  socketpair:   sock_no_socketpair,
  accept:       sock_no_accept,
  getname:      _hsl_sock_getname,
  poll:         datagram_poll,
  ioctl:        sock_no_ioctl,
  listen:       sock_no_listen,
  shutdown:     sock_no_shutdown,
  setsockopt:   sock_no_setsockopt,
  getsockopt:   sock_no_getsockopt,
  sendmsg:      _hsl_sock_sendmsg,
  recvmsg:      _hsl_sock_recvmsg,
  mmap:         sock_no_mmap,
  sendpage:     sock_no_sendpage,
};

static struct net_proto_family hsl_family_ops = {
  family:               AF_HSL,
  create:               _hsl_sock_create,
  owner:                THIS_MODULE
};
...

static int
_hsl_sock_create (struct net *net, struct socket *sock, int protocol)
{
  struct sock *sk = NULL;

  sock->state = SS_UNCONNECTED;
  sk = sk_alloc (current->nsproxy->net_ns, AF_HSL, GFP_KERNEL, &_prot);
  if (sk == NULL)
    goto ERR;

  sock->ops = &SOCKOPS_WRAPPED(hsl_ops);
  sock_init_data (sock,sk);

  sock_hold (sk);  /* XXX */
  ...

}

static void
_hsl_sock_destruct (struct sock *sk)
{
  struct hsl_sock *hsk, *phsk;

  if (!sk)
    return;

  ...
  sock_orphan (sk);
  skb_queue_purge (&sk->sk_receive_queue);

  sock_put (sk);
}

int
hsl_sock_release (struct socket *sock)
{
  struct sock *sk = sock->sk;

  /* Here goes logic to destroy net_devices */
  ...

  _hsl_sock_destruct (sk);

  sock->sk = NULL;

  return 0;
}
```

2) the daemon creates sockets in such way

```
fd = socket(AF_HSL, SOCK_RAW, 0);;
bind();
getsockname();
```

However I don't think _hsl_sock_create() should be calling sock_hold(), that would bump socket's reference count, but it's already set to 1 by sock_init_data(), and at socket delete phase sock_put() would decrement by 1, however this would not have the socket free;d and completely removed from the system.

So I experimented and removed sock_hold(); Now killing daemon yields in all references removed and 'rmmod' succedes, however the number of references after starting daemon is still 3.

I also have checked code at socket_create() whick calls internal function __socket_create(), which in turn calls try_module_get() and holds module's reference count. This appears to be the only place I've found that explicitly increments the module's refcnt.

I am still confused. Would anyone try to help understand what is happening?

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Mark